# Typical Unicode Error: Sublime vs. Atom

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, compiler-errors

I have a very very simple code (getting some content from Twitter)

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob


consumer_key = '7ezxdMbfSOFH9Q1IGZ774ojfd'
consumer_secret = 'JMG9HCeRpd2gPa30UxGyNCb9yRmOF4kr9MRIEv1trnJOzJEk8P'

access_token = '1735574195-d6R48bgxJv5YlhWHstr0eO3pg2usvZSh7fLd75D'
access_token_secret = '6VlIvRsDPgVksTM0u8SZQdEudETpjzGimkpxCdtJ0S7Dg'


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search('Trump')

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    print(analysis.sentiment)
```

I have installed Python 3. When I run the program through Sublime and Terminal (in my Mac) it works fine. On the other hand when I run it on Atom I get the very usual error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/Marion/test2.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(tweet.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 139: ordinal not in range(128)
```

where line 30 is the `print(tweet.text)`. I have looked at similar question but I have not managed to solve the problem (since I am a rookie in programming and Python).

Since I have Python 3 should the program not work also on Atom too since it works on Sublime? And, of course, how can I resolve it?

Comment: you're code works fine on my Atom(1.19.4) with python3. i'm using atom-runner and this is my config on config.cson:runner:
    scopes:
      python: "/usr/local/bin/python3"

Comment: Just a tip... you might not want to publish your private keys on a public forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on terminal run these three lines to set encoding 'utf-8':

echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bash_profile

echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

quit from atom then open it again.

or on your code

print(tweet.text.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: sorry for being so naive but I do not exactly know what you suggest to do. I have to add those commands in some directory through terminal? (completely beginner here)

Comment: add those lines on .bash_profile file to set encoding utf-8. on terminal run: echo "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Could you give me a reference where I can read what is going on? I would appreciate some advice. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html